# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway error when running flask app, but can run manually

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I have a flask app that I can run by doing `python app.py` from the command line, and can view it by going to localhost:5000. I'm trying to run it as a service with gunicorn/nginx, and have an nginx.conf file that looks like this

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myserver.com;
    root         /home/user/app/deviceapp/templates;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        }
    }
}
```

My nginx isn't great. I'm getting the error

```
2018/05/07 16:12:49 [error] 10419#0: *5 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.8.5.79, server: server.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "server.com"
```

along with a 502 Bad Gateway message. Is there something in my nginx.conf that's an obvious culprit?

Comment: Change `http://127.0.0.1:8001` to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`

Comment: Cheers for the reply, tried that and getting the same error unfortunately